# surf algorithm is included in emgu cv 3.1 or not? if included then how i can use it.... please Explain in detail am new in Emgu cv

Tags: c#, emgucv, surf

surf algorithm is included in Emgu CV 3.1 or not? if included then how i can use it. please Explain in detail am new in Emgu CV. Am trying to implement surf algorithm using c# but can't understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

For version 3.1, the name changed from SURFDetector to SURF

these are the links for version 3.0 and 3.1:
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0-rc1/document/html/8e5f3e80-3ebb-c21d-3e5a-0b792d2d2a1a.htm

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/dbec25e2-17bb-2070-fad3-454b3b4c0b6d.htm

Check the API files would help a lot.